# Mutually exclusive repos in build.gradle with Buildship

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have a multi-project as follows :

```
- A
  - settings.gradle
  - build.gradle
- B ( includes A )
  - build.gradle
```

In these I'm using the default repositories for the dependencies and plugins. We use Eclipse with **Buildship** and until now the resolution was mostly done with `Refresh Gradle Project`.

Problem : some colleagues and our CI server residing on a different network **must** use a **custom repository** for all dependencies and plugins as well. This virtual repo requires authentication, a certificate and proxies as well to spice up things.

Tried specifying both repos in `build.gradle`, but ordering them did not help. First one to fail will fail the build and one of them will **always** fail depending on the network. Thought about having a variable as the first line that could be overridden/read from a file, but since `pluginManagement` has to be the very first element in `settings.gradle` and is evaluated before anything, this option seems to fall out as well.

What I'd need is to easily toggle between these repos but still be compatible with Buildship somehow.

I really see no other way than creating multiple sets of these files like `build.1.gradle`/`settings.1.gradle` and overwriting the standard `build.gradle`/`settings.gradle` with their contents with some script or manually before each build.

Can this be achieved with Gradle or in a smart way I may have missed ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to achieve something really close to what I wanted.
There is an initialization script in gradle which can just override the whole environment dynamically. I didn't test it with Eclipse yet, but the CI is working flawlessly.

I'm using this `init.gradle` file (deployed on the CI server and in this internal network in GRADLE_USER_HOME for the users) to clear out the repository list defined in `build.gradle` and to override the repos in the `pluginMangement` section in `settings.gradle` as well.

Relevant links : [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) , [similar issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9016)